# how to obtain the general solution using separation of variables.

Tags: partial-differential-equations, integral-transforms

Consider the Laplace equation

$$\frac{\partial ^2 u}{\partial x^2} + \frac{\partial ^2 u}{\partial y^2} = 0,\quad\quad-\infty<x<\infty,\quad 0<y<\infty$$

with the boundary conditions

$$\lim_{|x|\rightarrow \infty} u(x,y)\rightarrow 0, \quad 0 < y < \infty,$$

$$\lim_{y\rightarrow \infty} u(x,y)\rightarrow 0, \quad -\infty < x < \infty,$$

$$u(x,0)=x, \quad 0 \leq x < 1,$$

$$u_y(x,0)=0, \quad 1 < x < \infty,$$

which is 100% taken from the book of Dean G. Duffy (Transform method for solving Partial differential equations second edition page 264 problem 6). I tried to solve using the separation of variables as suggested by the book but given boundary conditions limit my understanding of finding the general solution.
could you please help me out?.

Comment: There has to be some typo. The first one is not a boundary condition. The second boundary condition is also off. Taking the limit as y, while fixing y?

Comment: I've edited the question and copied down the original problem from the second edition of the textbook. The author tells you how to do the problem. The first step is to use separation of variables to show that the general solution is $u(x,y)=\int_0^\infty A(k)e^{-ky}\frac{\sin(kx)}{k}\,dk$. Have you done this step? Where did you get stuck?

Comment: yeah, this is exactly my problem; I got stuck while trying to obtain the first step and the second step.  so i need more explanation of how the author obtained the two steps.